TensorFlow Lite Image Segmentation in Flutter: Output shows only 2 out of 4 expected classes
I'm working on an image segmentation project in Flutter using TensorFlow Lite. My model is supposed to segment an image into 4 classes, but the output I'm getting only shows 2 classes. Here's the relevant part of my code:
Future<Uint8List> predict(img.Image image) async {
  if (interpreter == null) {
    throw StateError('Cannot run inference, Interpreter is null');
  }

  print('Loading image into TensorImage...');
  _inputImage = TensorImage(TfLiteType.float32);
  _inputImage.loadImage(image);

  print('Processing image...');
  final ImageProcessor imageProcessor = ImageProcessorBuilder()
      .add(ResizeOp(512, 512, ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR))
      .build();
  _inputImage = imageProcessor.process(_inputImage);

  final input = [_inputImage.tensorBuffer.buffer.asFloat32List()];

  // Prepare output tensor
  final output = {
    0: [List<List<List<double>>>.filled(512, List<List<double>>.filled(512, List<double>.filled(4, 0)))],
  };

  print('Running interpreter...');
  interpreter.runForMultipleInputs([input], output);

  print('Post-processing output...');
  final processedOutput = postProcess2(output[0][0]);

  print('Converting processed output to image...');
  img.Image _image = convertProcessedOutputToImage3(processedOutput);

  if (_image == null) {
    throw StateError('Image conversion failed');
  }

  print('Encoding image to PNG...');
  final Uint8List pngBytes = img.encodePng(_image);

  await saveBytesToGallery(pngBytes);
  print('Result image saved to gallery');

  return pngBytes;
}


List<List<int>> postProcess2(List<List<List<double>>> rawOutput) {
  final List<List<int>> processed = List.generate(512, (_) => List.filled(512, 0));
  List<int> classCount = [0, 0, 0, 0];

  for (int y = 0; y < 512; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 512; x++) {
      List<double> pixelProbabilities = rawOutput[y][x];
      int classIndex = argmax(pixelProbabilities);
      processed[y][x] = classIndex;
      classCount[classIndex]++;

      if (y < 5 && x < 5) {
        print("Pixel ($x, $y) probabilities: $pixelProbabilities, classified as: $classIndex");
      }
    }
  }

  print("Detailed class distribution:");
  for (int i = 0; i < classCount.length; i++) {
    print("Class $i: ${classCount[i]} pixels (${(classCount[i] / (512 * 512) * 100).toStringAsFixed(2)}%)");
  }

  return processed;
}

int argmax(List<double> list) {
  return list.indexOf(list.reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b));
}

img.Image convertProcessedOutputToImage3(List<List<int>> processedOutput) {
  final img.Image image = img.Image(512, 512);

  for (int y = 0; y < 512; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 512; x++) {
      switch (processedOutput[y][x]) {
        case 0:
          image.setPixel(x, y, img.getColor(0, 0, 0));      // Black for background
          break;
        case 1:
          image.setPixel(x, y, img.getColor(128, 128, 128)); // Medium gray for main wound area
          break;
        case 2:
          image.setPixel(x, y, img.getColor(192, 192, 192)); // Light gray for wound edges
          break;
        case 3:
          image.setPixel(x, y, img.getColor(255, 255, 255)); // White for deeper/necrotic areas
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  return image;
}


The output I'm getting shows this distribution:
Detailed class distribution:
Class 0: 0 pixels (0.00%)
Class 1: 0 pixels (0.00%)
Class 2: 3621 pixels (1.38%)
Class 3: 258523 pixels (98.62%)

As you can see, only classes 2 and 3 are present in the output, while classes 0 and 1 are completely absent.
I've checked the model's output, and it does produce probabilities for all 4 classes. Here's a sample of the raw output for a few pixels:
Pixel (0, 0) probabilities: [0.000976, 0.000002, 0.825438, 0.173583], classified as: 2
Pixel (1, 0) probabilities: [0.002672, 0.000000, 0.076512, 0.920817], classified as: 3
Pixel (2, 0) probabilities: [0.000085, 0.000000, 0.003305, 0.996610], classified as: 3

Is there anything in the predict function or interpreter initialization that could be affecting the output?

I think you haven't preprocessed the input correctly. You may need to add normalization to your image processor.
.add(NormalizeOp(127.5, 127.5))


I am actually normalizing the image before using it.
for (int y = 0; y < 512; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < 512; x++) {
    final pixel = resizedImg.getPixel(x, y);
    imageDataFloat32[index++] = img.getRed(pixel) / 255.0;
    imageDataFloat32[index++] = img.getGreen(pixel) / 255.0;
    imageDataFloat32[index++] = img.getBlue(pixel) / 255.0;
  }
}

normalized to the range [0, 1]

Try to do; (img.getRed(pixel) - 127.5)/ 127.5, (img.getGreen(pixel) - 127.5) / 127.5 and (img.getBlue(pixel) - 127.5) / 127.5 instead of dividing them by 255.0. But I would strongly suggest that you use tflite_flutter instead of flutter_tflite package. And should avoid the discontinued flutter helper package. Use image package to decode the image, resize it and get the pixels from that and normalize the input as above. Then use that byte buffer as the input for the model.
